# Push Custom Tile to All Users

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, ribbon, administration

Custom Tiles can be added to the Office 365 ribbon, and users can choose to add this to their app tiles. Is there a way which an administrator can forcefully pin the tile app to all users?

Answer (score 1):

Currently this feature is not supported by Microsoft according to the following reference: https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/359670

They might deploy this feature in the future.